# Possible to Manage Azure website via IIS snapin

Tags: iis, azure, asp-classic

I have moved a classic asp site from a a ISP where i could use the IIS snapin to manage it to an Azure website. 
The Website has a asp.net mvc site hosted from a virtual directory off that site which no longer works. I think I need to make this directory a virtual directory of the site on order to make this work, however I don't know how to do this without the IIS snapin. Can the snapin be used to manage Azure sites? or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot manage Azure websites using IIS Manager. You need to use the Azure Management Portal to control Virtual Directories and Applications.  See the [Azure Documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/#howtochangeconfig) (you will see a section on Applications and Virtual Directories).